# JQuery Datatable Question: Centering column data after data insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I have a data table that is initially empty and is populated after a particular Javascript call. After the data is inserted into the table, I'd like to center all of the data in one of the columns. I tried specifying this at the initialization step in this way:

```
dTable = $('#dt').datatable({ 'aoColumns': [ null, null, { "sClass" : "center" }] });
```

The data in the third column was not centered after the insertions were complete. I tried modifying aoColumns after the insertions and redrawing the table as well:

```
dTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[2].sClass = "center";
dTable.fnDraw();
```

This did not work either. So my question is simply how should I go about telling the data table to center the data in the third column?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Chris

Comment: I would recommend using Firebug to inspect the table cells to find out what styles are being applied. Perhaps something is being overridden?

Comment: @fudgey, I tried using CSS initially as well but to no avail.  Each time I add a row, I'm using a dTable.fnAddRow(r) call to add the data in array r.  Poking around with Firebug as Favio suggested, you see that the table body has a particular structure set up by the datatable plug-in to support various actions.  I could probably use CSS to fix the issue given what I've seen of the structure but that is far from elegant.  There's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your table gets multiple rows with multiple columns from AJAX data.  The third column should be centered.  Try this out:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) { //after AJAX completes
    //fill the table.
    $('#dt').children('tr').each(function(){ //for each row
      $(this).children('td').eq(2).attr('align', 'center');  //center the third column.
    });
  }
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't like using the  attributes, you could set the style attribute using [.attr(attributeName, value)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) or using [.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2), or add a class with [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: Thanks Bradley. I did something similar, reverting back to JQuery to populate the table prior to creating the datatable.  This way I could add a class for the entries in the third column and center them with CSS.  Now I'm having issues updating the datatable after it's created.  More investigation needed.